# Ambiguous tag JCL on StackOverflow

Tags: discussion, ambiguous-tags

This post uses the JCL tag. [Erlang how can I see application output via JCL on detached erl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17289648/erlang-how-can-i-see-application-output-via-jcl-on-detached-erl)

JCL is in the title. JCL means something in [erlang](/questions/tagged/erlang) (it means Job Control *Mode*, but there we are, it exists).

However, the [jcl](/questions/tagged/jcl) says this:

> Job Control Language (JCL) is a scripting language used on the IBM
>   mainframe operating systems z/OS and z/VSE (and predecessors) to
>   instruct the system on how to run a batch job or start a subsystem. In
>   z/VSE, it is sometimes referred to as JCS (Job Control Statements).

There are few Mainframe JCL-tag usages, and even fewer Erlang. It seems like overkill for a new tag for Erlang, but it may well come up again.

As an aside, JCL has a very specific meaning on the Mainframe. It is the Job Control Language which establishes the environment for any given program to run in. However, many mainframe users disregard specifics and regard as JCL anything which has a least one line of JCL in a file. Thus maybe 10% of those tagged JCL are actually JCL questions (but other than the single Erlang, they are all Mainframe questions).

The thing is, when I've grown up enough to do it (I'll be Edit-banned soon if I were to attempt it before then) should I even consider re-tagging? Most people using a search engine to find an answer will use JCL in the slack and incorrect way as well. Yet if no-one ever corrects, they won't know they are wrong about JCL.

(I did try to remove the tag from the question with a Suggested Edit, but was busted as usual. I guess I forgot to look at spelling/grammar/syntax for one of the multiple-reason rejections, and should have capitalised Then).

Before anyone thinks this is a duplicate (like that'll stop anyone) I did find an Answer here from @Pops saying to do this in this type of case.

So, question is, what do about the specific [erlang](/questions/tagged/erlang), and the curious use of the JCL tag anyway.

Comment: Why would they call it JCL?

Comment: Ambiguous question. Why would who call what JCL? The Mainframers, because many with little experience don't know. The Erlang designers, because L and M are quite close together in the Alphabet.

Comment: But that doesn't mean anything. I'd like to call `P.M.` as `P.L.`! I was referring to *Job Control Mode*.

Comment: I have no genuine clue as to why that happened (now that I know which and what was questioned). On your edit, why change a British spelling (or an English spelling) to an American? By engineing (now engaging) I meant using a search engine of individual choice. If I suggest googling it is far too domineering, and if I put it in quotes someone edits them out....

Comment: I couldn't find any references to the meaning of the word 'engineing' either on [Google](https://www.google.com/search?client=opera&q=engineing&sourceid=opera&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&channel=suggest), [Urban Dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=engineing) or any other dictionaries I frequently consult. I thought you meant about "people answering the question".

Comment: No problem. I just coined it, perhaps. Now how to update those so everyone can use it?